# Why does Krishna in certain verses of the gita state they are only his opinion?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

For example last chapter you can find this, also in 15 or 16 chapter. Why is that, since all other verses are strictly revelatory?

But even these actions should be done leaving
aside attachment and fruit, Q Partha ; that is my certain and best opinion. ( 6 )

And he who shall study this sacred; dialogue of
ours, by him I shall be worshipped with the sacrifice of wisdom, Such is My opinion. 18,70

Understand Me as the Knower of the Field in all Fields, O Bharata. Wisdom as to the Field and the Knower of the Field, that in My opinion is the Wisdom,
(2)13

Comment: His opinion = Shastra = revelatory. Vedas are literally Bhagavan's eternal orders, never created, always existing.

Comment: Can you give a specific verse?

Comment: 1) you need to give specific verses that pertain to your question. The question is unclear as it now stands. 2) Is not Krishna's 'opinion' revelatory?

Comment: No. Because why would it  be specifically be declared as an opinion. I can easily find it or tell you which ones. Granted it's not easy to know all the verses, but gita is only 18 chapters so if you are eligible to answer you should know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I have eddited this in the question. The epic that contains Gita also has a part where Krishna in his sleep by the tree after the war, ponders on the question of dharma, dreams of asking people what dharma is and letting pass all but the one with demonic dharma. There Krishna is in distress and I can't help but notice that he seems to question some of his actions.

Comment: So maybe some parts of the gita are not as set in stone as thaugh.

Comment: Whose translation are you quoting? Can you add the link to it? Also better to use [blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) when quoting someone.

Answer (score 2):

Good question indeed.

Sri Krishna said

> एतान्यपि तु कर्माणि सङ्गं त्यक्त्वा फलानि च।
>
> कर्तव्यानीति मे पार्थ निश्िचतं मतमुत्तमम्।।18.6।।
>
> Even these actions too must be performed by relinishing attachment and
>   fruits : This is my considered best opinion, O son of Prtha !

---

Sri Krishna also said, after delivering the entire BG, as follows:

> इति ते ज्ञानमाख्यातं गुह्याद्गुह्यतरं मया।
>
> विमृश्यैतदशेषेण ***यथेच्छसि तथा कुरु***।।18.63।।
>
> To you has been imparted by Me this knowledge , which is more secret
>   than any secret. Pondering over this as a whole, ***do as you like***.

---

When Sri Krishna, who was a friend, relative, guide to Arjuna  gave the **Viswarupa Darshana**, and delivered an elaborate lecture on Spiritual concepts, why should he said ***do as you like***?

The secret/subtlety lies in the fact that Sri Krishna was explaining various issues to Arjuna, **as a Guru**.

A true guru like Sri Krishna, **will never say** that the disciples should follow his/her orders.

A true Guru will always shows the way to the disciple in a subtle and humble way and it is for the disciple to follow the route, toil and achieve the result.

The subtle message that Guru gives in  being humble is in future, when the disciple gets the REALISATION, he should follow the suit and remain humble.

---

Sri Krishna is a TRUE guru.

When Sri Krishna said that it is my opinion, we have to remember that he was guiding in a humble way.

Comment: Very well explained. 

Comment: I see it also implying that a student should also come to the realization on his own, not only by faith.